# Perl Mechanize form fields with no name

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am trying to submit a form using

```
my $fields = {
'f1' => 'type_contract',
'f2' => '0',
 .
 .
 .
};
$mech->submit_form(with_fields => $fields);
```

the problem is that some of the fields in the form either have no names of duplicate names. How can I use "id" instead of "name" to set data on form fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by first forming the header properly. Please read [HTTP::Headers](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Headers.pm)

```
my $cont_h = HTTP::Headers->new(
'Host'  => 'http:// [the url]',
'User-Agent' =>     'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130307 Firefox/17.0',
'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
.
.
.
.
);
```

The mistake I did was passing Post data as a Hash. Post data is byte string which is also content in this case.

```
my $cont_post_data = 'chargingContractHistoryCsvDto.searchType=type_contract& chargingContractHistoryCsvDto.searchItem=0&chargingContractHistoryCsvDto.searchDateFrom='.$start_t.'&chargingContractHistoryCsvDto.searchDateTo='.$end_t.'&';
```

Formed the HTTP request. Please read [HTTP::Request](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request.pm)

```
my $cont_req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $URI, $cont_h, $cont_post_data);
```

And used perl mechanize to send the request.

```
my $cont_response = $mech->request($cont_req);
```